# jsPDF - import main script and plugins.fromHTML into VueJS project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jspdf

I'm trying to use the fromHTML function of jsPDF in a Vue project and I don't know how to import the key plugin which is `fromHTML`.

I'm importing per the docs: `import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";` but I don't know how to correctly import the fromHTML function. I'd rather not use script tags.

My print method looks like this:

```
handleSavePdf() {
  const doc = new jsPDF("p", "in", "letter");
  doc.fromHTML(this.html, 0.5, 0.5, { // fromHTML not a function
    width: 7.5,
  });
  doc.save(`${this.itemDetails.fields["Inventory No."]}.pdf`);
},
```

Thoughts?

Comment: check [jspdf guide](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html#~html), `new jsPDF().html(domObj, options)` is the one generate a PDF from an HTML element or string using.

Comment: @Sphinx thanks. Now I have to figure out how to render SVG objects in my page because the PDF saves blank with no content and there is a `error loading svg` error. Is there a plugin for that?

Comment: i dont know too much about jspdf, you may have to google it.